# CNN accuracy increases while decrease in Loss increases

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm training a CNN model on a small data set of 4 category 64 by 64 images. Besides the fact that I'm having overtraining issues, something strange happens.

Right from the start, the training loss decreases. The validation loss increases (again, probably overtraining). But the validation accuracy of my model increases. This is weird. How is it possible that my accuracy increases while my loss goes up?

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to say without seeing your code. Typically, there is some leakage that is unintended and your accuracy and loss are actually being calculated on different distributions. It's usually a small typo or confusion with variable names. Just on the terminology side of things, we talk about ***overfitting***, not overtraining.